# Как на языке си(си++) определить что память выделена на стеке/bss, а не в куче?

Tags: c, память

Вообще проблема следующая:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
char buf[5]; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ssize_t len = 0;
    char *buffer=buf;
    //buffer = realloc(buffer,10);
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    ssize_t a = getline(&buffer, &len, f);
    printf("%zd", a);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

при вызове библиотечной функции getline и передаче ей указателя не на кучу, функция отрабатывает в штатном режиме и без ошибок. Если использовать свою реализацию getline(точнее честно скопированную getdelim, например, с [getdelim](https://fossies.org/dox/sccs-5.08/getdelim_8c_source.html), то ловим ошибку:

> *** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x080497ed ***
>   Aborted

Понятно что проблема в realloc и передаче ей указателя. Но может кто в курсе как это обойти?

Comment: Если вы хотите просто пользоваться getline(), то @Harry дал ответ. Или все же интересует вопрос в заголовке (например, хотите хакнуть ту же getline)? (в ответе укажите @ мой-ник, иначе нотификация мне не дойдет)

Comment: @avp я лишь хочу понять почему стандартная getline не ложится при передаче в нее указателя на выделенную память. Как она так реализована?

Comment: Она смотрит 1) на buffer и если 0, то делает malloc и заносит размер в len 2) на len и если очередной символ не поместится в буфер, то делает realloc, меняя buffer и len. Если в buffer указатель на выделенную malloc-ом память, то все ОК. Если на память в стеке   или статическую, то realloc валится (этот адрес не соответствует структуре блоков динамической памяти). В 2-х словах так, если что-то еще не ясно, уточните, попробую рассказать подробней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один ответ - потому что это ответ на совсем другой вопрос :)

Итак - спрошено в комментарии:

> как определить, где выделена память, которую предположим нам передали в указателе? или это невозможно? Реализация, которая приведена по ссылке - не работает, в ней проверяется хватается ли памяти и если нет то увеличивает её через realloc. Но если использовать встроенную в Linux реализацию проблем с глобальной памятью нет.

Берем реализацию библиотеки GCC, например, [отсюда](http://mirrors-usa.go-parts.com/gcc/libstdc++/old-libg++-releases/). Открывам `getline`:

```
getline (lineptr, linelen, fp)
     char** lineptr;
     size_t* linelen;
     FILE* fp;
{
  return _IO_getdelim (lineptr, linelen, '\n', fp);
}
```

Ищем реализацию `_IO_getdelim`, и, *как я и предполагал*, находим в ней следующее после вступительных действий:

```
if (*lineptr == NULL || *n == 0)
{
    *n = 120;
    *lineptr = (char*) malloc(*n);

    if (*lineptr == NULL)
    {
        result = -1;
        goto unlock_return;
    }
}
```

Так что, если вы передаете в параметре длины 0, то функция считает, что буфера нет, и выделяет его наново с помощью `malloc`!

Попробуйте вызвать `getline` в вашем коде **правильно**

```
char buf[5]; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ssize_t len = 5;   // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    char *buffer=buf;
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    ssize_t a = getline(&buffer, &len, f);
    printf("%zd", a);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

и посмотрите на результаты...

Answer (score 4):

Насколько мне известно из [man-a по `getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html), например, то либо вы передаете ей адрес нулевого указателя и адрес целочисленного значения 0 :), либо ненулевой указатель и его размер, но ненулевой указатель на память, полученную вызовом `malloc`.

А вы передаете ненулевой указатель на глобальные данные, и нулевую длину. И что вы от нее хотите? Скорее всего, все пролетит на первом же `realloc`.

Обойти?

Вариант 1:

```
ssize_t len = 0;
char *buffer= NULL;
ssize_t a = getline(&buffer, &len, f);
```

Вариант 2:

```
ssize_t len = k;  // Сами решите, чему оно равно
char *buffer= malloc(k);
ssize_t a = getline(&buffer, &len, f);
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то так...

P.S. Ваша ссылка, кстати, что-то не работает...

Comment: странно у меня работает ссылка. было использовано несколько разных исходников getline, все они почти идинаковые. суть работы функции я знаю. Меня интересует почему она не ломается, когда ей передаёшь НЕвыделенную память. Как это реалиизовано?

Comment: Так это уже совсем другой вопрос - это вопрос о внутреннем устройстве `getline`. Тут нужны конкретные исходники. Как я понимаю, те, которые по ссылке - не работают. Так какой именно код вас интересует? Учтите, кстати, что в разных компиляторах и даже в разных версиях могут быть разные реализации.

Comment: меня интересует следующее - как определить, где выделена память, которую предположим нам передали в указателе? или это невозможно? Реализация, которая приведена по ссылке - не работает, в ней проверяется хватается ли памяти и если нет то увеличивает её через realloc. Но если использовать встроенную в Linux реализацию проблем с глобальной памятью нет.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, слабо верится, что есть версия, которая идет таким путем - выясняя, где находится нужная память. Мне больше верится в то, что, увидев переданный в качестве длины нуль, она просто выделяет новую память, а не выполняет `realloc`...

Comment: Смотрите мой второй ответ. Мои догадки оказались верны... **Не проверяет** `getline`, где находится буфер. Да и возможно ли это вообще? Разве что каким-то очень нехорошим, нестандартным, грязным хаком...